# HTML styling with borders

Tags: html, css

making a new jsp and got a mock-up from some analyst.  Notice the sections "Favorites" and "Favorite Management Options" with the lines and border around them.  How would I style something like that?

All the other stuff is straight forward like the select boxes and data fields.

[image]

Comment: This layout is crappy - why emulate it?

Comment: Because it landed on my desk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the following pattern:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Favorites</legend>
 ... form elements
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

The fieldset is the wrapper:

```
fieldset {
    border:1px solid #d0d0d0
}
```

the legend is the title:

```
legend {
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold
     border:1px solid #d0d0d0
}
```

You can apply various CSS stylings to make it look the way you want.

See: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms

Answer (score 3):

Relatively easily.

Use a `fieldset` adding border values to the css. Then use a `legend` tag for the "Favourites" and "Favourite Management Options". Give the legend css for `background-color` and `border` and use `position:relative; top:-10px` (at a guess) to shift it up over the fieldset border.

Answer (score 1):

They are created using the fieldset and legend html tags. You can get the details here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp

Comment: Thanks alot mate...I normally just write java back end stuff....html and css is not my forte....but I can do it if Im pointed in the right direction...thanks